# What is the difference between these two sql scripts?

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I use this one in the sqlite

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS developer(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,name TEXT,skill TEXT,yearsOfExperience INTEGER);
INSERT INTO developer(name, skill, yearsOfExperience) VALUES ('Simon', 'Ionic', '4');
INSERT INTO developer(name, skill, yearsOfExperience) VALUES ('Jorge', 'Firebase', '2');
INSERT INTO developer(name, skill, yearsOfExperience) VALUES ('Max', 'Startup', '5');
```

While this one is from the exported mysql db

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

They're both sql but why does the second one is not accepted in sqlite when I import it?
I hope there's someone who can tell me what's the difference so I can make a copy of the second sql into a sqlite readable

Comment: Can you share the exact error message?  Never mind, SQLite has no such engine called `InnoDB`...that's 100% a MySQL thing, and my guess is there is some other MySQL specific syntax in the second table.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have the same guess. I hope there's someone who can tell what it is so I can make a copy of the second sql into a sqlite readable

Comment: For future reference, try to phrase your question more clearly.  If you had asked how can I migrate this table from MySQL to SQLite, you might have not gotten downvoted.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that. English is not my language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refactor the current MySQL `CREATE TABLE` statement for the second table to this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (
    user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    username TEXT,
    password BLOB,
    first_name TEXT,
    last_name TEXT,
    email TEXT,
    created INTEGER
)
```

SQLite's syntax does not support specifying an engine (e.g. InnoDB).  Also, there is no `varchar` column type, but there is `TEXT` and `INTEGER`.  Columns will have a `NULL` value by default, so if `NULL` is the default value you want, then you don't need to explicitly specify it.  SQLite follows the SQL standard for escaping column and table names, and uses double quotes, not backticks, for that.  So I removed the backticks from all the column names.

Finally, I chose to make your `created` timestamp an `INTEGER`.  You could store seconds since the epoch, i.e. a UNIX timestamp.  An alternative to this would be to store the timestamp as `TEXT`, but this might be harder to work with depending on what you plan to do.

Comment: Oh so it accepts only 2? (TEXT and INTEGER) that sucks. So the password can't be encrypted/hash right?

Comment: @JaneDoe Check [here](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html) for a list of SQLite data types.  You can encrypt a user's plain text password and then store it as a `BLOB` type.

Comment: Okay @Tim thank you for your help. I learned something new today

Comment: As did I.  Have a look [here](https://www.sqlite.org/src/doc/trunk/ext/userauth/user-auth.txt) to see some official documentation which uses `BLOB` for the password, at least in one example.

Comment: Thanks again. I appreciate your help, Tim

Comment: An example of why it is folly to think you can easily migrate code between RDBMSs.

Answer (score 0):

mysql is not sqllite you must update your second sql query as below for be accepted by sqllite (because the type timestamp does not exist in sqllite ):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
`user_id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
`username` varchar(50),
`password` varchar(300) ,
`first_name` varchar(200),
`last_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
`email` varchar(300),
`created` TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: This is not valid SQLite syntax.

Comment: @abderrahime Can you tell me more about it? Is there anything I can use as timestamp?

Comment: TIMESTAMP is like an intger (the number of second after 1970) so you can replace it by text or type NUMBER but i think you can also use TIMESTAMP :  try this : CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (
user_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
username TEXT,
password TEXT ,
first_name TEXT,
last_name TEXT NOT NULL,
email TEXT,
created TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);